# Programmatically generate requirements.txt file

Tags: python, subprocess, pip, requirements.txt

I'm trying to generate a requirements.txt file programatically. This way I can diff it against a second .txt file. So far I've tried the following, but they only output the requirements to console (No .txt file is generated).

So far I've tried

```
    import pip

    pip.main(["freeze",">","requirements.txt"])
```

and

```
    from subprocess import call

    call(["pip","freeze", ">","requirements.txt"])
```

If I attempt to run the same command manually in terminal though, the file is generated without issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ask pip to directly provide the list of distributions

## Script `myfreeze.py`

```
import pip
with open("requirements.txt", "w") as f:
    for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
        req = dist.as_requirement()
        f.write(str(req) + "\n")
```

Then you get expected content in your `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 4):

```
subprocess.Popen(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=open('/tmp/pip.log', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pip for this is [strongly discouraged](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243) by the developers of pip. It is also broken in more recent versions of pip. Here is a summary of the approach suggested on the linked Github issue. Very similar to the accepted answer but using the `pkg_resources` module instead.

```
import pkg_resources


def generate_pip_freeze() -> str:
    requirements = ""
    for dist in pkg_resources.working_set:
        req = dist.as_requirement()
        requirements += f"{req}\n"
    return requirements
```

or more succintly:

```py
def generate_pip_freeze() -> str:
    return "\n".join(
        str(dist.as_requirement()) for dist in pkg_resources.working_set
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that `pkg_resources` is deprecated, you should do this with `importlib.metadata` (or `importlib_metadata`, its backport to earlier Python versions)

```py
from importlib.metadata import packages_distributions, version
  
installed = {pkg for pkgs in packages_distributions().values() for pkg in pkgs}
req_str ="\n".join(f"{pkg}=='{version(pkg)}'" for pkg in installed)

with open("requirements.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(req_str)
```

Comment: the single quotes around the version aren't accepted by pip if used with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, they should be removed.